# Keep RStudio focussed on 'Source' and 'Plots' when executing code line-by-line

Tags: r, rstudio

For a presentation, I want to run through an R script line-by-line (with RStudio). I use the `CTRL + ENTER` command. Throughout the presentation, I only want to show two panes: the 'Source' pane and the 'Plots' pane.

I can prearrange that view with the 'pane' tab in RStudio's top ribbon and with minimising some of the panes. However, when I run the first line, the 'Console' window pops up again.

How can I suppress this behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggestion would not be to minimise the console window, but to make it small enough that it is irrelevant.

A second option would be that you can "pop-out"the source by dragging the tab out of the source window (not sure of shortcut for this). From here you can move around to have the source in the popped out window alongside a plots panel. The source would be on top of the console